# Show multiple selection of images from gallery

Tags: android

Can someone please tell me how to allow the gallery to select multiple images from gallery intent. Currently, this code opens the gallery. But I'm not able to figure out how to allow the gallery to select multiple images

```
 public Intent getPickImageChooserIntent() {

    Uri outputFileUri = getCaptureImageOutputUri();

    List<Intent> allIntents = new ArrayList<>();
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();

    Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setPackage(res.activityInfo.packageName);

        if (outputFileUri != null) {
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        }
        allIntents.add(intent);


    }

    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    galleryIntent.setType("*/*");
    List<ResolveInfo> listGallery = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(galleryIntent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo res : listGallery) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(galleryIntent);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setPackage(res.activityInfo.packageName);
        allIntents.add(intent);

    }

    Intent mainIntent = allIntents.get(allIntents.size() - 1);
    for (Intent intent : allIntents) {
        if (intent.getComponent().getClassName().equals("com.example.healthpassport.MainActivity")) {
            mainIntent = intent;
            break;
        }
    }
    allIntents.remove(mainIntent);

    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(mainIntent, "Select source");
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, allIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[allIntents.size()]));
    return chooserIntent;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want this library is very useful for displaying and getting the images. It is also used for getting gifs.[git](https://github.com/zfdang/android-multiple-images-selector)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can get images from this below query, you can also get only videos from this query and both at same time by changing the query "MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL" to "MediaStore.videos.Media.EXTERNAL"

```
 //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
private void populateImagesFromGallery()
{
   //if permission is not granted than return
    if (!mayRequestGalleryImages())
    {
        return;
    }
    final String[] columns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID};
    final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN;
    ArrayList<Media> imageUrls = new ArrayList<>();



        imageUrls.addAll(loadPhotosAndVideosFromNativeGallery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, orderBy, true));


    //ahsan adapter
    initializeRecyclerView(imageUrls);
}
```

this is another function to load all images

```
 //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
private ArrayList<Media> loadPhotosAndVideosFromNativeGallery(Uri tableName, String[] columns, String orderBy, boolean isImage)
{
    //final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
    //final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN;
    Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(
            tableName, columns, null,
            null, orderBy + " DESC");

    ArrayList<Media> imageUrl = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < imagecursor.getCount(); i++)
    {
        imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
        int dataColumnIndex;
        Log.e("cursor", imagecursor.toString());
        if (isImage)
        {
            dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        }
        else
        {
            dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
        }

        imageUrl.add(new Media(imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex), imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN), isImage));

    }


    return imageUrl;
}
```

call the adapter initialize function pass this function your array to populate

```
 //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
private void initializeRecyclerView(ArrayList<Media> imageUrls)
{
    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, imageUrls);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 3);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new ItemOffsetDecoration(this, R.dimen.item_offset));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

    //it will restrict to onbind view holder to call again and again and call only for the item count of the array
    recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(imageAdapter.getItemCount());
}
```

adapter

```
 public class ImageAdapter extends         RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.MyViewHolder>
  {

private ArrayList<Media> mImagesList;
private Context mContext;
private SparseBooleanArray mSparseBooleanArray;

private List<Media> selectedImages ;


public void setOnEventListener(OnEventListener listener) {
    mOnEventListener = listener;
}


public interface OnEventListener {
    void onSelect();
    // or void onEvent(); as per your need
}

private OnEventListener mOnEventListener;

public ImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Media> imageList)
{
    mContext = context;
    mSparseBooleanArray = new SparseBooleanArray();
    mImagesList = imageList;
    selectedImages = new ArrayList<>();


}


public void selectAll()
{
    for ( int i=0; i < mImagesList.size(); i++) {
        mSparseBooleanArray.put((Integer) i, true);

    }

    notifyDataSetChanged();
    mOnEventListener.onSelect();

}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
public List<Media> getCheckedItems()
{
    ArrayList<Media> mTempArry = new ArrayList<Media>();



    return selectedImages;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
@Override
public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return position;
}

CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener mCheckedChangeListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {

    }
};

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{

    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.row_multiphoto_item, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder,  int position)
{

    final String imageUrl = String.valueOf(mImagesList.get(position).getFilePath());

    final int pos = position;


    Glide.with(mContext)
            .load("file://" + imageUrl)
            .centerCrop()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .into(holder.imageView);

    if (selectedImages.contains(mImagesList.get(pos)))
    {
        holder.ic_Selected.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_select_item);
        holder.itemView.setAlpha(0.5f);
    }
    else
    {
        holder.ic_Selected.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_unselect_item);
        holder.itemView.setAlpha(1f);
    }

 //   holder.ic_Selected.setImageResource(selectedImages.contains(mImagesList.get(pos)) ? R.drawable.ic_select_item : R.drawable.ic_unselect_item);

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            holder.itemClicked(pos);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    return mImagesList.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    ImageView imageView;
    public ImageView ic_Selected;

    public MyViewHolder(View view)
    {
        super(view);


        imageView =  view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        ic_Selected =  view.findViewById(R.id.ic_Selected);
    }

    public void itemClicked(int pathPosition)
    {

        // if selected item is contain that path than remove from list and if not than add in the list
        if (selectedImages.contains(mImagesList.get(pathPosition)))
        {
            selectedImages.remove(mImagesList.get(pathPosition));

        }
        else
        {
            selectedImages.add(mImagesList.get(pathPosition));

        }

        mOnEventListener.onSelect();

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

}